# Where to use HTTParty to call API given user input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, httprequest, httparty

I am trying to make a page that uses user input and a call to the Stack Exchange API using HTTParty to return information. Where should I put the file below, as given in one of the HTTParty [examples](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/stackexchange.rb) for HTTParty to be able to call `StackExchange.new(user_input, 1)` (where `user_input` would be some variable provided on the front end by a user)? Also, is there a more general way to call APIs in Rails? I am trying to retrieve information from multiple APIs and return all of that information to the user. Could I combine multiple get requests into one class?

Code:

```
class StackExchange
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'api.stackexchange.com'

  def initialize(service, page)
    @options = { query: { site: service, page: page } }
  end

  def questions
    self.class.get("/2.2/questions", @options)
  end

  def users
    self.class.get("/2.2/users", @options)
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, u can combine into one method and return data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ruby, you can write:

```
#some_file.rb:

class A
  def initialize(x)
    @x = x
  end

  def dostuff
    puts "doing stuff with #{@x}"
  end
end

class B
  def go
    a = A.new(10)
    a.dostuff
  end
end

b = B.new
b.go

--output:--
doing stuff with 10
```

That demonstrates that a class defined in one file can use another class defined in the same file.

You could also change the name of the classes to:

```
class StackExchange 
  def initialize(x)
    @x = x
  end

  def dostuff
    puts "doing stuff with #{@x}"
  end
end

class UsersController
  def go
    a = StackExchange.new(10)
    a.dostuff
  end
end

b = UsersController.new
b.go

--output:--
doing stuff with 10
```

In a rails app, rails takes care of executing the lines:

```
b = UsersController.new
b.go
```

When you create a route to a `controller#action`, and then you enter the matching path in your browser, rails creates the Controller object and calls the action method.

All you have to do is take care of writing the action methods inside the controller class:

```
class UsersController
  #You write this stuff:
  def go
    a = StackExchange.new(10)
    a.dostuff
  end
end
```

So for a very simple solution, you can paste your StackExchange class at the top of the file containing your Controller class, and then inside any of the Controller's actions/methods, you can call `StackExchange.new`.

But if the actions(=methods) in some of your other Controllers also need to use the StackExchange class, then instead of pasting the StackExchange class at the top of each Controller file, you can put the StackExchange class in a file called `stack_exchange.rb`, and put the file in a central location somewhere where all your Controllers will have access it.

One choice for the central location is the `lib/` directory. You could create a sub directory in the `lib/` directory and put the stack_exchange.rb file in there:

```
lib/my_classes/stack_exchange.rb
```

Then at the top of the file that contains one of your Controller classes that needs to use the StackExchange class, you would just need to write:

```
require 'my_classes/stack_exchange'
```

That's shorter than having to paste the whole StackExchange class at the top of the file.

But there is an even briefer solution.  In ruby, once a class is required it doesn't need to be required again, so you don't actually need to put the require statement at the top of every Controller file that needs to use the StackExchange class.  Instead, you can use a configuration file to require the StackExchange class once, and then you don't have to paste the require statement at the top of *any* of the Controller files:

```
#config/initializers/my_require_classes.rb
require 'my_classes/stack_exchange'
```

Note that if you make any changes to a config file, you have to restart your server.  In fact, I find that require statements are pretty *sticky*, so if I change a require statement, sometimes I need to restart the server.

Another choice for a central location for the StackExchange class is in the `app/` directory.  In `rails 5`, the `app/` directory is autoloaded, which means that rails creates the require statements for you, and you can happily use the classes placed in the `app/` directory without worrying about the require statements.

Answer (score 1):

> Where should I put the file below?

There are a few options. Personally, I would create a `services` directory under the `app` directory and put it in there. That way, rails will auto load the file. And, I would tend to call it `StackExchangeService` (sort of the way that `Controllers` always have `Controller` at the end), but some people don't like it that way.

> Is there a more general way to call APIs in Rails?

I'm not sure what this means.

> Could I combine multiple get requests into one class?

Sure, you could do something like:

```
class MultiFetchService

  attr_accessor :args

  class << self

    def call(args={})
      new(args).call
    end

  end  # Class Methods

  #==============================================================================================
  # Instance Methods
  #==============================================================================================

    def initialize(args)
      @args = args || {}
      assign_args
    end

    def call
      {
        stack_exchange: StackExchange(user_input, user_id)
        foo:            FooService(some, other, args)
      }
    end

  private

    def assign_args
      args.each do |k,v| 
        class_eval do 
          attr_accessor k
        end
        send("#{k}=",v)
      end
    end

end
```

Which you could call something like:

```
MultiFetchService.call(
  user_input: user_input, 
  user_id: 1, 
  some: :some, 
  other: :other, 
  args: :args
)
```

Due to that `assign_args` method, you'll have a method in your service for each key that you send into `MultiFetchService` (in this example, `user_input`, `user_id`, `some`, `other`, `args`)

Comment: So would the services directory be on "the same level" as folders like app, bin, config, db, etc.? Also, by "more general way to call APIs in Rails", I mean is there a good example of using HTTParty on Github (other than the provided examples) that I would be smart to look at?

Comment: Apologies, I was moving too fast. A `services` directory would go under the `app` directory at the same level as `controllers`, `models`, `views`, etc.

Comment: That clarifies a lot of my question. The only other part I was wondering about is where I might find a good example of HTTParty being used in a project? If this isn't possible, I understand. I just figured you might have run into something along these lines.

Comment: Hm. I haven't looked in a very long time. I ended up writing a gem that wraps HTTParty so, although I use HTTParty *all the time*, I no long interact with it directly, but rather through my gem. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem! I actually ended up finding a few examples I like on GitHub. [Here](https://github.com/SamirArap/Recipes4All) and [here](https://github.com/ATL-WDI-Exercises/rails_httparty_movie_app) for anybody in the future who might need them.